# Why I am unable to authenticate in aws using the files located upon .aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In my bootstrtap.tf I did:

```
module "ec2-instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "5.6.0"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}


provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  access_key = "XXXXXX"
  secret_key = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

And I did manage to do:

```
terraform plan
```

But if did not want to specify hardcoded credentials therefore I did:

```
aws configure
```

And I changed the provider with:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "default"
}
```

But I got:

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, decomposing request: net/http: invalid header field value for "Authorization"
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on bootstrap.tf line 18, in provider "aws":
│   18: provider "aws" {
│
```

It sees that terraform ignores the default aws files despite having the correct credentials. I did try to see whats wrong with the aws cli:

```
aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************X  shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************/XXX shared-credentials-file
```

And my `~/.aws/config` is:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json
```

And my aws cli version is:

```
aws-cli/2.15.17 Python/3.11.6 Linux/5.15.0-94-generic exe/x86_64.linuxmint.21 prompt/off
```

Therefore why I am unable to use the aws settings file with default profile?

As [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#shared_config_files) says the nessesary files do exist:

```
$ ls -l $HOME/.aws/config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 43 Φεβ  15 11:49 /home/pcmagas/.aws/config
$ ls -l $HOME/.aws/credentials
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 119 Φεβ   6 18:53 /home/pcmagas/.aws/credentials
```

As asked upon:

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity

Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
```

The command is unable to parse the response.

Comment: Does running `aws sts get-caller-identity` return what you expect? This will show you if the default profile is working okay.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Terraform, you'll want to create a variables.tf file to declare variables for credentials:

```
    variable "aws-access-key" {
      type     = string
      sensitive = true
    }
    
    variable "aws-secret-key" {
      type     = string
      sensitive = true
    }
```

Next, update your providers.tf file (or in your case, bootstrtap.tf):

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source  = "hashicorp/aws"
          version = "~> 4.16"
        }
      }
    
      required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
    }
    
    provider "aws" {
      region      = "eu-west-1"
      access_key  = var.aws-access-key
      secret_key  = var.aws-secret-key
    }
```

To pass values to these variables, you have options like:

**1- Via .tfvars file:** Although I do not recommend it, you can pass variables via a .tfvars file. If the file is not in the root directory, you can use the following command:

```bash
    terraform plan -var-file="/path/to/variables.tfvars"
```

**2- Via Environment Variables:** You can set environment variables for your variables like so:
export TF_VAR_=xxxxx
in your case:

```bash
export TF_VAR_aws-access-key=xxxxx
export TF_VAR_aws-secret-key=xxxxx
```

Then, run terraform plan. It will read the credentials with no extra flags.

**3- CLI:** You can pass variables directly via the CLI like this:

```bash
    terraform plan -var="aws-access-key=xxxxxx" -var="aws-secret-key=XXXXXX"
```

Choose the method that best suits your workflow and security requirements.

Comment: If the user is the only terraform user, which will run plan, apply, ecc... I suggest to use `profile` in place of access  and secret keys within the `provider` block